# jQuery UI nested droppables - make draggable a droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to be able to drag a draggable into a droppable. Then, when I drag in another draggable prevent the user from dropping it on the previously dropped draggable, but still drop it on the droppable. That is such a ridiculous sentence I've added an image to illustrate below and a jsfiddle of what I've tried so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/u4pAf/6/

[image: detect if draggable is being placed over a dropped draggable]

Below is the code on jsfiddle. Just a demo to try and get something working. I though the best approach to detecting if a draggable is over a dropped draggable is to make the draggables droppables too, and set the accept parameter to false, so it accepts nothing.

css:

```
.draggable-elem { background:red }
.drag1 {width: 100px; height: 40px;}
.drag2 {width: 150px; height: 80px;    margin-top:10px;}


.boundary_active{
    outline: solid 12px darkviolet;
}
.boundary{
    background:cyan; 
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="boundary">  
    <p>droppable</p>
</div>

<div class="draggable-elem drag1">1</div>
<div class="draggable-elem drag2">2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 jQuery('.boundary').droppable({        
    over : function( event, ui ) { 
        jQuery(ui.helper).css('background', 'blue').text('OVER DROPPABLE'); 
    },
    out : function( event, ui ) { 
         jQuery(ui.helper).css('background', 'red').text('draggable');    
    },
    drop : function(ev, ui) {    
          this_clone = jQuery(ui.helper).clone(false)
          .css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0})
          .removeClass('ui-draggable')
          .removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging')
          .removeClass('draggable-elem')
          .addClass('droppable-elem')
          .addClass('ui-droppable');
          jQuery('.boundary').append(this_clone);//append to boundary
    },
    accept : '.draggable-elem',
    activeClass : 'boundary_active',
    tolerance : 'fit'
});

jQuery( '.draggable-elem' ).draggable({
    helper : 'clone',
});

jQuery('.dropped-elem').droppable({
    greedy : true,
    over : function( event, ui ) { 
        jQuery(ui.helper).css('background', 'yellow').text('OVER DRAGGABLE'); 
    },
    accept : '.none',
    tolerance: 'touch',
    activeClass : 'boundary_active',
});
```

Comment: what are those functions `aperture_drop` and `outside_boundary`? could you update the fiddle with them? it's also unclear if in the scenario that the blue draggable wasn't dropped yet it would be able to accept another draggable (imagining from the picture)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to hit update on fiddle.  It is as it should be now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tolerance` option:

> Specifies which mode to use for testing whether a draggable is
>   hovering over a droppable. Possible values:
>
> - "fit": Draggable overlaps the droppable entirely.
> - "intersect": Draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50% in both    directions.
> - "pointer": Mouse pointer overlaps the droppable.
> - "touch": Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount.

in your case you can use `touch`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6eGGT/

### UPDATE

You have to setup the cloned element as droppable, by using `droppable` on it, check out the accept selector that now not select anything (`.none` selector).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PmjW6/

Comment: Thanks Irvin, I see what you mean. Unfortunately it hasn't helped yet. The problem I'm facing as you can see in this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4pAf/6/ is the dropped draggable isn't working as a droppable. For debugging I set up the over event to detect it and so far nothing. The tolerance setting will be helpful if I can get past this issue!